# LangChain with Llama2 Stuck at "> Entering new AgentExecutor chain..."

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, langchain, large-language-model, llama

So I'm totally new to LLMs and I want to make a simple chatbot to ask him questions about a csv that I have. I made the simpliest code with a 2 rows csv which looks like this:

```
!pip -q install langchain langchain_experimental
!pip show langchain
!pip -q install langchain
!pip install ctransformers
from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
import sys


import pandas as pd

llm = CTransformers(model="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q3_K_S.bin", model_type="llama", max_new_tokens=512, temperature=0.1)

from langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits.csv.base import create_csv_agent

agent = create_csv_agent(llm, "rating.csv", verbose=True, separator=",")
#agent.agent.llm_chain.prompt.template
agent.run("how many rows are there?")
```

However, when I run it, it gets to the agent run with no errors, and shows "> Entering new AgentExecutor chain..." on the prompt, but never ends.

I would appreciate some help on what's going on here.

Thanks!